# Syntax for multiple cases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, syntax-error, case

I have a MySQL update statement which is attempting to reset two columns: label and PersTrCode. (This is in a Coldfusion program.) I'm doing this with CASE statements but I can't seem to get the syntax right -- I keep getting an error.  The code:

```
<cfquery name = 'nonull' datasource = "Moxart">
update FinAggDb
set Label = CASE 
 WHEN PersActIncOutg = 'I' && PersTrCode IS NULL THEN 'Total Income'
 WHEN PersActIncOutg = 'O' && PersTrCode IS NULL THEN 'Total Expense'
 WHEN PersActIncOutg IS NULL && PersTrCode IS NULL THEN ' '
 ELSE PersTrCode
END 
SET PersTrCode = CASE 
 WHEN PersTrCode IS NULL THEN 'Total'
 ELSE PersTrCode
END 
</cfquery>
```

The error is the usual informative statement:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET PersTrCode = CASE WHEN PersTrCode IS NULL THEN 'Total' ELSE PersTrCode ' at line 8

Are multiple `CASE` statements not allowed?  Or can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update statement has only one `set` clause, with the various columns you want to update separated by commas. Also, note that it's more common to use `and` and not `&&`, although both are valid in MySQL:

```
update FinAggDb
set Label = CASE 
 WHEN PersActIncOutg = 'I' AND PersTrCode IS NULL THEN 'Total Income'
 WHEN PersActIncOutg = 'O' AND PersTrCode IS NULL THEN 'Total Expense'
 WHEN PersActIncOutg IS NULL AND PersTrCode IS NULL THEN ' '
 ELSE PersTrCode
END
,  -- comma here, not a second "set" clause
PersTrCode = CASE 
 WHEN PersTrCode IS NULL THEN 'Total'
 ELSE PersTrCode
END
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and I just did not see it.